# Git - Waiting for your editor to close the file

Tags: git

I have notepad++ 64bit, yesterday I tried to make a merge and I got the message:

```
utente@utente-01 MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/progetto (ETICHETTA)
$ git pull origin master
From https://server/project/_git/repositorium
 * branch            master    -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

I couldn't finish the merge. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same issue, you need to update the path to notepad++ (or another editor) to the right one. Once you have the right path to notepad++.exe, you can make something like:

```
utente@utente-01 MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/progetto (ETICHETTA|MERGING)
$ git config core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

That should solve the problem.